# Btrfs balance makes filesystem read-only and unbootable

Tags: btrfs

I have btrfs filesystem across two 1TB SSDs. Metadata is raid1 and data is raid0. I started to run out of space, so I decided to convert data to `single` and add a larger capacity 2TB HDD. I ran `sudo btrfs balance start -dconvert=single -mconvert=raid1 /` on the mounted filesystem. After about 30min I could no longer save my files, with messages indicating the filesystem was read-only. The balance operation finished or terminated on its own and when I checked the filesystem (`sudo btrfs fi usage /`) I saw that only 40GB of data were in single and the rest was still raid0. I tried to reboot the computer but cannot boot into the operating system.

Why did this happen and how can I recover my filesystem and boot into my system? Am I unable to boot into my system because part of the data is single and the rest is raid0?

I could boot into an external usb drive. From there I could attempt to continue the original balance operation so that the data is single. Is this a good idea? Should I instead try to revert to raid0 (i.e., `-dconvert=raid0`)? Is there a better solution?

I'm operating a very modern version of linux, 5.9 something, although I don't know the exact revision at the moment for obvious reasons. I already have a backup of my data, but I would prefer to recover from this without repartitioning the drives.

Comment: @A.B the data is fortunately already backed up

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/btrfs/comments/hwpcaj/full_filesystem_btrfs_read_only/